# Can an aggregator be a type 1 adversary?

Tags: signature, certificateless-crypto

In a certificateless aggregate signature scheme, can a signature aggregator be a type 1 adversary (external attacker who can have access to secret value of a user)? I thought signature aggregator is always assumed to be trustworthy in a certificateless aggregate signature scheme.